# ekko-lightbox with webpack-encore: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

I would like to use Symfony's webpack-encore to include [ekko-lightbox](https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox).

I've created a working jsFiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/92vq1z2b/. It uses the same versions of bootstrap, jQuery and ekko-lightbox as I do.

In my local Symfony project it doesn't work however. When I click on a "lightboxed" image, I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined
at new Lightbox (ekko-lightbox.js:97)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (ekko-lightbox.js:649)
at Function.each (jquery.js:362)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:157)
at jQuery.fn.init._jQueryInterface [as ekkoLightbox] (ekko-lightbox.js:645)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (members.js:8)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)
```

Line 97 of ekko-lightbox.js reads as follows:

```
this._isBootstrap3 = $.fn.modal.Constructor.VERSION[0] == 3;
```

Somehow, webpack-encore seems to mess up the javascript files. But I can't find the problem.

My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
// webpack.config.js
// ...
.addEntry('global', './assets/js/global.js')
.addEntry('public', './assets/js/public.js')
.addEntry('members', './assets/js/members.js')
// ...
```

The global.js file includes bootstrap, jQuery and the like:

```
// global.js
require('../css/global.scss');

var $ = require('jquery');
require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
```

The members.js file includes ekko-lightbox:

```
// members.js
require('../css/members.scss');

require('ekko-lightbox');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
});
```

In my HTML code the global.js is loaded before the members.js:

```
// HTML code that loads the javascript files
<script src="/build/global.js"></script>    
<script src="/build/members.js"></script>
```

By the way: For some reason, webpack-encore uses the minified version of ekko-lightbox, i.e. ekko-lightbox.min.js. Even in dev mode. My expectation was that webpack-encore would always use the non-minified version in dev mode. I had to change the ekko-lightbox package.json file to change this behavior (the 'main' entry in the package.json previously pointed to the .min.js file, now it points to the non-minified version). I think that the 'main' entry should always point to the target file without any file extension (that's how it's defined in the package.json of bootstrap). That is, it should look like `"main": "dist/ekko-lightbox"` instead of `"main": "dist/ekko-lightbox.js"` or `"main": "dist/ekko-lightbox.min.js"`.

**Version information:**

```
Google Chrome 63
"@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.17.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"ekko-lightbox": "^5.3.0"
```

Update: I have noticed that bootstrap v4 is no more in beta. But the problem persists after running `npm update`. My new npm package versions read as follows (only top-level):

```
+-- @symfony/webpack-encore@0.17.1
+-- bootstrap@4.0.0
+-- ekko-lightbox@5.3.0
+-- jquery@3.3.1
+-- node-sass@4.7.2
+-- popper.js@1.13.0
+-- sass-loader@6.0.6
`-- webpack-notifier@1.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it after lots of debugging. The problem was how I included jQuery and bootstrap. In my global.js I explicitly required jQuery with a `require()` call. However, this is automatically performed by webpack-encore via the line `.autoProvidejQuery()` in my `webpack.config.js`. Also, this auto provision of jQuery seems to occur for each javascript file referenced by `webpack.config.js`. That is: My global.js, public.js and members.js got each a separate instance of jQuery (by the way: this also slows down page load times!).

Obviously, these separate jQuery instances messed up the bootstrap module registration (they register under `jQuery.fn[MODULE_NAME]` or `$.fn[MODULE_NAME]`).

The solution is to create a so called [shared entry to your webpack.config.js](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/shared-entry.html).

My webpack.config.js now looks like this:

```
// ...
.addEntry('global', './assets/js/global.js')
.addEntry('public', './assets/js/public.js')
.addEntry('members', './assets/js/members.js')

.createSharedEntry('vendor', [
    'jquery',
    'popper.js',
    'bootstrap'
])

// allow sass/scss files to be processed
.enableSassLoader()

// allow legacy applications to use $/jQuery as a global variable
.autoProvidejQuery()
// ...
```

My global.js doesn't require jQuery or bootstrap anymore, because they're already included in the shared module. There's only a single require() left for global CSS definitions.

```
// global.js
require('../css/global.scss');
```

My members.js did not change, except that I added the line `require('ekko-lightbox/dist/ekko-lightbox.css');` for including ekko-lightbox own CSS definitions.

Finally, I just had to extend my base HTML template to include the new vendor.js and the manifest.js before any other javascript files:

```
{% block javascripts %}
<script src="{{ asset('build/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/global.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```